# Converting image in clipboard to JPEG

Tags: excel, image, powershell, jpeg, clipboard

I figured out how to copy a range in an Excel sheet with a PowerShell script. I wrote that output in a variable to transform it to a JPEG later on.
I've done that with the Excel application & `Windows.Forms.Clipboard` methods (`GetImage()`).

Now my question is how to transform my current clipboard to a JPEG in a PowerShell script.

It was not possible for me to transform the clipboard with the save method. 
My last command looked something like this:

1. `$clipboard.Save("C:\Data\picture.jpeg")`
2. `$clipboard.Save(("C:\Data\picture.jpeg", "jpeg"))`
3. `$clipboard.Save("C:\Data\picture.jpeg", "jpeg")`

None of these three solutions worked. I always got the error that the variable is **null**.

At work I am also not allowed to use PowerShell version 5. Because of this I'm as well not able to use the cmdlets `Get-Clipboard` & `Set-Clipboard`.

I know it's possible to just paste the clip into paint and then save it manually but I don't want to do that on my own, but with a PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi,  can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41491456/edit) to show us how you declare `$clipboard` and what you put in it?

Comment: Not sure if this will help in what you are trying to achieve: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136985/vba-copy-cells-paste-as-a-picture-then-save-as-a-picture

Answer (score 2):

Use [`[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard::GetImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage.aspx) for fetching an image from the clipboard, then call the image object's [`Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) method with the correct format parameter:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$file = 'C:\path\to\output.jpg'

if ([Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::ContainsImage()) {
  $img = [Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()
  $img.Save($file, [Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)
} else {
  Write-Warning 'No image in clipboard.'
}
```

Note that for clipboard access to work you must be running in STA mode (Single Thread Apartment):

> **Note**
>   The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your **Main** method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

Comment: I will try this tommorow at work. Thank you in advance Ansgar!

Comment: It does not work. Always getting the error that $e is null.

Comment: `'##1##
$rng = $Worksheet.range("A2:O41")
$pic = $rng.CopyPicture(1,1)
$e=[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()
$e.Save($file1, [Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)


##2##
$rng = $Worksheet.range("A42:O124")
$pic = $rng.CopyPicture(1,1)
$e=[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetImage()
$e.Save($file2, [Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)`

Comment: Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ $e.save('C:\Daten\Bild1.jpg',[System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @Robin If you take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193594.aspx), you'll notice that `1` is not a valid value for the second parameter of `CopyPicture()`. Make it `$rng.CopyPicture(1,2)`, or just `$rng.Copy()`. And the next time please add updated code and error messages to your question instead of burying it in comments (where it becomes unreadable).