# Range to Image (JPEG) is not working anymore (from Excel 2007 to O365)

Tags: excel, vba, o365-flow

I need to convert a range to a picture and saved that picture as a JPEG which I can then use for different purposes (e.g. email sending). 
Now I have switched to O365 compared to Excel2007 and with that switch the picture is always empty with a border only. It seems like there were any issues within my code which I have attached below. 
Please do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks and best regards,
Susann

```
Sub Range_To_Image()
'erstellt von den markierten Zellen eine Bilddatei (GIF)
Dim Zellbereich As Range
Dim Anz_Markierungen As Integer
Dim Bild As Picture
Dim Diagramm As ChartObject

On Error GoTo Hell 'falls "Abbrechen" gedrückt wird
'Zellen markieren (Bildbereich)
Set Zellbereich = Sheets("OE Daily Summary").Range("A6:O66")
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Zellbereich.Copy
Worksheets.Add
Set Bild = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True)
Bild.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set Diagramm = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, Bild.Width, Bild.Height)

With Diagramm
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OE_Daily_Summary" & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Diagramm = Nothing
Set Bild = Nothing
Set Zellbereich = Nothing
Exit Sub

Hell:
MsgBox "", , "Abbruch"
End Sub
```

Comment: This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32136985/2127508) might be of use

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why the `Picture` object is necessary. There is a `Range.CopyPicture` method.

Bu main issue is that the `ChartObject` needs be activated before pasting the picture to it.

The following works for me using `Excel 385`.

```
Sub Export()

 Dim oWs As Worksheet
 Dim oRng As Range
 Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
 Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long

 Set oWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OE Daily Summary")
 Set oRng = oWs.Range("A6:O66")

 oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
 lWidth = oRng.Width
 lHeight = oRng.Height

 Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)

 oChrtO.Activate 'This is necessary
 With oChrtO.Chart
  .Paste
  .Export Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OE_Daily_Summary" & ".jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
 End With

 oChrtO.Delete

End Sub
```

See also: [VBA - Range to jpg picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091390/vba-range-to-jpg-picture/42092375#42092375).

Comment: Hi Axel, Now it works! Thanks a lot and best regards, Susann!